# Compare columns in excel

Tags: java, c++, excel

community
I am looking to compare partial strings  of data thats in two seperate  columns. And if its a match print a statement in a third column like " yes its a match" or "there is no match". The problem is there is extra data in the first column so it wont be an exact match so I'm essentially searching or comparing certian words. I have over 8000 rows and doing it one by one would take forever is there a function I can use in excel to make this process easier.

Comment: How about an `=if($a1 = $b1,"yes it's a match","there is no match")` (assuming column a and b are supposed to be compared?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you can combine `SEARCH()` and `ISERROR()`.

`SEARCH()` returns the index of the start of a string match, or the `#VALUE` error otherwise. Using `IF(ISERROR())` on this will let you output something based on whether there was a match or not.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(B2,A2)),"No Match", "Match")
```